# handle array with multi dimension (python)

Tags: python, arrays

I want to build a dynamical insert query by python. The datasource is an array with multi dimension. The array looks like that:

```
[<insight>{
  "action":[
    {
      "name":"col1",
      "value":"20",
    },
    {
      "name":"col2",
      "value":"30",
    },...
  ],
  "call":"a"
}]
```

The problem is that "action" is not sort and most of time only some of the columns are included. So the second insight maybe looks like that:

```
[<insight>{
  "action":[
    {
      "name":"col3",
      "value":"10",
    },
    {
      "name":"col2",
      "value":"50",
    },...
  ],
  "call":"b"
}]
```

In summary i have 30 columns. Is there an effectively way to build a insert query? The result could looks like that:

```
call | col1 | col2 | col3
----------------------- 
a    |  20  |  30  |  0 
b    |  0   |  50  |  10
```

My try works but is very intensive.

```
sql="INSERT INTO t_x ('col1','col2','col3') VALUES (("
cols=["col1","col2","col3"]
for insight in insights:
  for i in range(len(cols)):
    for j in range(insight["action"]):
      if cols[i]==insight["action"][j]["name"]:
        sql += insight["action"][j]["nvalue"] + ","
        break
      if j==len(insight["action"][j]["name"]):
        sql += "0,"
  sql = sql[:-1] + "),"
sql = sql[:-1] + ")"
```

The core idea is that i have s static INSERT front string (insert into t_x **(COL1,COL2,COL3)**...)
For the rest i need to loop through all of the actions and compare the names with all column names. The result looks like that:

> sql = "INSERT INTO t_x ('col1','col2','col3') VALUES
>   (('20','30','0'),('0','50','10'))"

It would be great if i can replace the searching by loops with directly statements like that:

> "INSERT INTO t_x ('col1','col2','col3') VALUES
>   ((insight['action'][j]['col1'],insight['action'][j]['col2']...

Knows anybody how i can better handle this format? I have not much experience

Comment: This isn't valid JSON.. `[<insight>{`

Comment: if it's json format did you try json module provided with python?

Comment: Please don't build sql by string-splatter.  Create a list of tuples and then use a sql statement that takes this list. (and please fix your json, you're also missing commas between list elements...)

Comment: sorry you are right. i edited my post. @thebjorn if i understand you right i couldnt use a string which include all data in string format. I agree with you that a list would be the best solution but how can i upload a list directly (i use MySQLdb as db bib)

Comment: See the last paragraphs in my answer for the exact syntax to use for myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v tried to interpret your json and assigned it to variable `insights`:

```
insights = [{
  "action":[
    {
      "name":"col1",
      "value":"20",
    },
    {
      "name":"col2",
      "value":"30",
    }
  ],
  "call":"a"
},
{
  "action":[
    {
      "name":"col3",
      "value":"10",
    },
    {
      "name":"col2",
      "value":"50",
    }
  ],
  "call":"b"
}]
```

create a helper function to make a data structure to hold column values:

```
def empty_columns(n):
    return {'col%d' % i: 0 for i in range(1, n+1)}
```

Next loop through the json filling up rows of parameters (using names instead of integer indexes, only two levels of for-loops, and some blank lines to make the code have room to breathe):

```
def get_query_params(insights):
    n = 5  # number of columns, adapt to your needs
    res = []

    for action in insights:
        cur = [action['call']] + [0] * n
        cols = empty_columns(5)

        for colval in action['action']:
            cols[colval['name']] = colval['value']

        for i in range(1, n+1):  # fill the parameter array from cols
            cur[i] = cols['col%d' % i]
        res.append(cur)

    return res
```

you can now verify that the params are a list of lists:

```
params = get_query_params(insights)
print params
```

the output will be (I've added a newline for clarity):

```
[['a', '20', '30', 0, 0, 0], 
 ['b', 0, '50', '10', 0, 0]]
```

finally, grab a cursor from your connection (`cn`), and use the `executemany` method to pass all parameters at once:

```
c = cn.cursor()
c.executemany("""
    insert in to t_x (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
              values (%s,   %s,   %s,   %s,   %s)
""", params)
```

this is called a parameterized call and the `%s` are placeholders (MySQL uses `%s` other databases can use e.g. `?`, check your db library). Don't confuse this with string interpolation.

Comment: i´m realy grateful for your answer. i try to understand what you are doing. The idea is that i build a new list (empty size depends on the source array). after that i loop through the original array and copy the data in form which i need to my new array. in the end i upload the whole list to my db?

Comment: That is correct. It's taking the json structure, extracting the data that should be sent to the database into a new data structure (i.e. building a list of lists), and finally passing the new datastructure to `cursor.executemany(..)`.

Comment: awesome. unfortenetily your code doesnt works (the json is a little bit more complicate thats why i cant take the code 1:1). But the idea works fine. Thank you a lot!